# Class Phar not found in VPS

Tags: php, vps, phar

I have purchased a VPS in Dreamhost. Now Im trying to run `php composer.phar install` but it says:

> Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in
>   /home/john/mysite.com/composer.phar on line 13

Since I have found out that I have these directories:

> /usr/local/php   /usr/local/php53 /usr/local/php54

and, for example, in `/usr/local/php53/bin/` I have this:

```
phar  phar.phar  php  php-cgi  php-config  phpize
```

,how can I run `php composer.phar install` without errors?

If you need more information about content in folders I will give it of course.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
php -d extension=phar.so composer.phar [... your command ...]
```

This includes the phar extension for the current runtime. Works for shared / VPC servers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not have the phar extension installed or configured correctly. It might be worth checking the output of a call to phpinfo().

Comment: @SteveV this is the output for `phpinfo()`: http://pastebin.com/b0FFXUhL Anyway, this is the information related to the server (CGI), so I dont know why do you think this is usefull since (I think) I'm using PHP CLI this time

Comment: hmmm well through the server it looks like phar is loaded (you can see lines like Phar: PHP Archive support       enabled). 

It's possible that you have a different config when running CLI. Can you get the output of phpinfo() when running from the command line? Maybe it uses a different php.ini

Comment: I'm also getting the same error when running through putty. 
In phpinfo(), I found this line that contains phar "--enable-phar=shared"

can you please tell me what is the issue and how to fix it..thanks